# How to fill progressBar using separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, jprogressbar

I'm currently working on the following problem : How to use a thread in order to fill a progress bar (step by step) when the start button is clicked.
I encountered no problems building the thread or the progress bar.
However, when it came to filling the bar I proceeded as following :

```
public class event implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Try t = new Try(250);
        Thread MyT = new Thread(t);


       MyT.start();   

        try {
            MyT.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        pr.setValue(pr.getValue()+25);
        System.out.println("check");

        try {
            MyT.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        pr.setValue(pr.getValue()+25);
        System.out.println("check");


    }
}
```

The problem here is that I expected the bar to be filled with 25 units after 500 ms, then again filled with other 25 units(step by step) after 5000ms. Instead my program won't fill the bar with 25 after 500 ms, but with 50 after 5000 ms. Why is that and how can I make the bar charge gradually, without modifying the thread class ?

Comment: it's not clear how your code works and what's in `Try` but i would pass a reference of the progresBar `pr` to `Try` and let it set the values, based on it's progress in the work??

Comment: You can't sleep in an `actionPerformed()` method. You're just holding up the event thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know the question is old but maybe it helps someone.

I have implemented a progress bar class that provides a simple method, which fills the progress bar to a certain value in a specified amount of time.

Use like this:

```java
   // create progress bar
   ProgressBar progressbar = new ProgressBar();

   // fill progress bar in steps each one second
   progressbar.fillInMills(1000, 25);
   progressbar.fillInMills(1000, 50);
   progressbar.fillInMills(1000, 75);
   progressbar.fillInMills(1000, 100);

   // resets to zero
   progressbar.reset();
```

```java
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;

public class ProgressBar extends JProgressBar {

        Thread thread;
        final int MAX = 100;
        final int MIN = 0;

        public ProgressBar() {
            super(HORIZONTAL);
            setMinimum(MIN);
            setMaximum(MAX);
        }

        /**
         * Fills the progress bar to the specified level in the specified time.
         * 
         * @param millis the time in milliseconds
         * @param fillTo the level in percentage
         */
        public void fillInMills(final int millis, final int fillTo) {
            thread = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    final int startAt = getValue();
                    final int timeBetweenSteps = millis / Math.max(fillTo - startAt, 1);
                    for (int i = startAt; i <= fillTo; i++) {
                        setValue(i);
                        Thread.sleep(timeBetweenSteps);
                    }
                } catch (final InterruptedException ignored) {
                    // thread is cancelled
                }
            });

            thread.start();
        }

        /**
         * Resets the ProgressBars level to zero.
         */
        public void reset() {
            if (thread != null) {
                thread.interrupt();
            }
            this.setValue(0);
        }
    }
```

If you need advanced features of the JProgressBar, see this [Oracle Tutorial on Progress Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for detailed info.